# Bootstrap form layout

Tags: php, formulário, bootstrap-4, yii

estou tentando fazer um formulário com bootstrap em que vai ter um campo titulo, um campo estado, um campo para po conteudo, campo para tags e um botao. Acontece que quero colocar o campo do titulo e o do estado lado a lado, o campo do conteudo logo abaixo, seguido do campo das tags e de seguida o botao... Mas está um pouco bugado, este foi o resultado do que eu fiz ate agora...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, o botão criar está totalmente desalinhado, seguido do campo do conteudo que está com width a 100%, mas não vai até ao final.

Aqui está o codigo (estou a fazer isto com yii framework e bootstrap)

```
   <?php
/* @var $this NodeController */
/* @var $model Node */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="box-body">

    <?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'node-form',

        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    ));
    ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>



<!--- Estado --->
    <div class="form-group row flex-v-center" style="width: 30%; float: right;">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'Estado'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'node_status_id', CHtml::listData(NodeStatus::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'designation'), array('empty' => '--Selecione uma categoria--', 'class' => 'form-control col-xs-3')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'node_status_id'); ?>
    </div>



<!---- Titulo -->
    <div class="form-group row flex-v-center" style="width: 70%; float: left;">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'title'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'title', array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 100, 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'title'); ?>
    </div>




<!--- Conteudo --->
    <div class="form-group row flex-v-center" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'content'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textarea($model, 'content', array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 500, 'id' => 'summernote', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'content'); ?>
    </div>




<!----- Tags --->
    <div class="form-group row flex-v-center" style="width: 50%; float: left;">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'tags'); ?>

        <!--- Criei este input em html para este ser preencido enquanto o que está em php vai receber os valores deste -->
        <input type="text" id="taggenerator" class="tm-input form-control"/>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'tags'); ?>



        <div class="col-sm-12 tags-show">
            <!---Este é o hidden field que vai receber e enviar para a db os valores do input-->
            <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'tags'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>



<!----Botao--->
    <div class="form-group row flex-v-center buttons" style="float: left;">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(($model->isNewRecord ? 'Criar' : 'Guardar'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jovem vc precisa usar o Grid do Bootstrap row/col, da forma que vc fez ficou completamente desformatado... Recomendo que tire uns 30 min para ler a documentação do Grid https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Tentei montar um exemplo colocando as coisas em ordem, no CSS deixei as colunas com borda, apenas para vc visualizar melhor como ficou distribuído.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
[class*="col-"] {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
 <div class="box-body">

  <?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
     'id' => 'node-form',
   
     'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    ));
    ?>

  <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

  <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-4">
    <!--- Estado --->
    <div class="form-group  flex-v-center">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'Estado'); ?>
     <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'node_status_id', CHtml::listData(NodeStatus::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'designation'), array('empty' => '--Selecione uma categoria--', 'class' => 'form-control col-xs-3')); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model, 'node_status_id'); ?>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-8">

    <!---- Titulo -->
    <div class="form-group  flex-v-center">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'title'); ?>
     <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'title', array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 100, 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model, 'title'); ?>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
    <!--- Conteudo --->
    <div class="form-group flex-v-center">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'content'); ?>
     <?php echo $form->textarea($model, 'content', array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 500, 'id' => 'summernote', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model, 'content'); ?>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">

    <!----- Tags --->
    <div class="form-group d-flex flex-v-center">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'tags'); ?>

     <!--- Criei este input em html para este ser preencido enquanto o que está em php vai receber os valores deste -->
     <input type="text" id="taggenerator" class="tm-input form-control" />
     <?php echo $form->error($model, 'tags'); ?>



     <div class=" tags-show">
      <!---Este é o hidden field que vai receber e enviar para a db os valores do input-->
      <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'tags'); ?>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-6">


    <!----Botao--->
    <div class="form-group  flex-v-center buttons">
     <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(($model->isNewRecord ? 'Criar' : 'Guardar'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>

  <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

 </div><!-- form -->
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo!

Comment: @NelsonPacheco tranquilo jovem! Tire um tempinho para ler sobre o Grid, vc vai usa-lo 90% do tempo, é bem entender bem como ele funciona... []´s